# Deep learning for tokenization

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I would like to train an LSTM network in order to solve tokenization problem.

My corpus looks like this:

> The computer is broken.
>   00010000000010010000001

And my expreience code in python:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from keras.utils import np_utils
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(7)
maxlen = 100

filename = 'corpus_mini.txt'
data = np.array([list(line.rstrip('\n')) for line in open(filename, encoding='utf-8').readlines()])
Xdata = data[::2]
Ydata = data[1::2]

chars = set()
for sentence in Xdata:
    for char in sentence:
        chars.add(char)
chars = sorted(list(chars))       
char_to_int = dict((c, i) for i, c in enumerate(chars))


X = []
y = []
seq_length = 30
for s in range(0,len(Xdata)):
    sentence = Xdata[s]
    for i in range(0, len(sentence) - seq_length, 1):
        seq_in = sentence[i:i + seq_length]
        X.append([char_to_int[char] for char in seq_in])
        seq_out = Ydata[s][i + seq_length]
        y.append(char_to_int[seq_out]-8)

# reshape X to be [samples, time steps, features]
X = np.reshape(X, (len(X), seq_length, 1))      
# one hot encode the output variable
cat = np_utils.to_categorical(y)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, input_shape=(X.shape[1], X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X, cat, nb_epoch=12, batch_size=3)
```

I tried a lot of variation, but I can't figure out what's wrong with my code. I can not teach it to learn even spaces, It is possible that this problem is not suitable for LSTMs?

Comment: From your last layer I can see you're trying to do some sort of binary classification. Can you provide a couple example training examples?

Comment: Finally, I found out where is the problem. seq_out variable should be  "Ydata[s][i + seq_length - 1]" and everything works fine. But the result is not satisfying for example you can not learn abbreviations, so I have to use other structures where both side of the current char is matters. If you really need I can send training examples in Hungarian language.

Comment: I'm not sure yet what's the problem formulation here, but maybe you could frame it as a sequence tagging problem. In this case, you still feed a sequence of characters to the LSTM, but the labels (0 or 1) get "shown" to each timestep of the LSTM and each timestep would have a sigmod output. Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, it is a sequence tagging problem where I feed (forward) a sequence of characters to the LSTM to figure out where is the word endings. This simple model is enough to learn spaces, punctuation and so on but Its not enough to learn abbreviations, for example: "George W. Bush" It thinks that the punctuation after W is a word ending but actually it's not. I hope if I use feed forward LSTM and a feed backward LSTM fed with chars after predictable char will help. Maybe it can learn rules like Capital letter + point + Capital letter should not be separate.

Comment: In my second version I used char vectors(embedding layer), but It's not helped at all. Maybe I can create a model which can deal with abbreviations, but It would be to computationally expensive against rule based models, and probably less accurate because of the lack of training examples. I'm a bit disappointed.